# Puts blood or pours blood?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, word-request

1. The nurse takes some blood sample from his hand with a syringe, and then **put** it in a small glass tube.
2. The nurse takes some blood sample from his hand with a syringe, and then **pours** it in a small glass tube.

Which one this is correct? For me, both look something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both have errors, but not necessarily relating to the verb choice between put and pour as either one can be used (albeit with slightly different meanings).

For both sentences, one would either say "The nurse takes a blood sample..." or "the nurse takes some blood samples..." depending on how many blood samples we're talking about. I think you're only talking about one since you use the pronoun "it" in the second part, in which case you would want your sentence to be this:

> The nurse takes a blood sample from his hand with a syringe, and then puts/pours it in a small glass tube.

(You wouldn't use "some" here because what you're talking about is the **sample,** which is singular.)

Now, as for the slight difference between the usage of **put** and **pour** in this context, it is as follows:

- If you say "put," that simply conveys that the sample of blood is going from the syringe to the glass tube, without any specificity as to how. And that's perfectly fine.
- If you say "pour," that conveys the idea of opening the top of the syringe and tilting it so that the blood comes out of it and spills into the glass tube.

Hopefully this is helpful! One last thing, the word for a glass tube that holds liquids (or other small amounts of stuff) is a vial.

Comment: I thought put can't used with liquids like water, blood, etc.

Comment: Sure you can! There are other, more colorful terms you can use as well -- spray, squirt, drizzle, empty into -- but there isn't anything intrinsically wrong with using "put."

Comment: I think I've never seen a nurse taking blood sample from anyone's hand before. Perhaps from a finger, but that wouldn't be enough to put or pour into a glass tube. It think it's probably *from his arm*, or even better *from a blood vessel in his arm*.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I was a little puzzled at first too, but I remembered that for people with particularly tricky veins, doctors and nurses sometimes use butterfly syringes on the back of the hand.

Comment: Oh, that's possible then. Thank you. I can learn something from this question too! :-)

Comment: I've had blood taken from the back of my hand.  It's unpleasant!

Comment: @snailplane: it's less unpleasant than having somebody repeatedly try to get blood from the inside of your elbow, and repeatedly fail. That's *really* unpleasant.

Comment: @PeterShor In my case, the only reason they tried the back of my hand was because they'd failed five times elsewhere :-/

Answer (score 0):

I'm a healthcare provider and often describe the matter like this -

> A nurse *collects* a blood sample from his hand.

The good part of this sentence is - when someone *collects the blood sample,* it means drawing the venous blood and collecting it in something (a test-tube/vial or these days a [vacutainer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacutainer)).

Check out the slide 5 [here](http://www.usada.org/blood/).